# Image isn't displayed in ImageViewZoom

Tags: android, android-viewpager, universal-image-loader

I'd like to use [ImageViewZoom](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom) with [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) in ImagePagerActivity.

So, what I did:

1. I added imageviewtouch.jar to project classpath.
2. In ImagePagerActivity I changed one line in instantiateItem() function. I commented line where is ImageView and replaced it to ImageViewTouch (4. and 5. line)

   ```
   @Override
   public Object instantiateItem(View view, int position) {
       final View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pager_image, null);
       //final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
       final ImageViewTouch imageView = (ImageViewTouch) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);

       final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.loading);
       final TextView textView = (TextView)imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.text);

       imageLoader.displayImage(images[position], imageView, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {


           public void onLoadingStarted() {
               spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           }


           public void onLoadingFailed(FailReason failReason) {
               String message = null;
               switch (failReason) {
                   case IO_ERROR:
                       message = "Input/Output error";
                       break;
                   case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                       message = "Out Of Memory error";
                       break;
                   case UNKNOWN:
                       message = "Unknown error";
                       break;
               }
               Toast.makeText(ImagePagerActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);
           }


           public void onLoadingComplete(Bitmap loadedImage) {
               spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ImagePagerActivity.this, R.anim.fade_in);
               imageView.setAnimation(anim);
               anim.start();
           }


           public void onLoadingCancelled() {
               // Do nothing
           }
       });

       ((ViewPager) view).addView(imageLayout, 0);
       return imageLayout;
   }
   ```
3. In /res/layout/item_pager_image.xml I replace **ImageView** to **it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouch**

   ```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:padding="1dip" >

     <it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouch
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

     <ProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/loading"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:visibility="gone" />

   </FrameLayout>
   ```

I run this Android application, but when I choose Image Pager in menu screen, there is no image displayed, only black screen. In logcat I see that image was downloaded and displayed... If I change ImageViewTouch to original ImageView, everything is OK, but of course there is no zoom feature. If someone knows what I do wrong, I'd be very grateful. (sorry for my English)

Comment: Have you tried it without the fade in animation?

Comment: Yes, I've tried, but it hasn't solved problem...

Comment: Why your ImageViewTouch has ```android:layout_height="0dp"```?

Comment: It's my stupid mistake. It should be: android:layout_height="wrap_content" Now, everything is OK. Thank you NOSTRA.

Comment: I have applied the above technique and it does the trick. The 2 finger touch pinch can zoom the image nicely. however, when I double tap, the image goes black. any hints ? @NOSTRA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change ImageViewTouch parameter from `android:layout_height="0dp"` to other value.

Comment: Hi NOSTRA, I am also facing the same problem with viewpager. I am able to zoom the image, and if the image is in zoom position i am not able view the other corners of the image. if an image is zoomed and i am at center position, if i want to see the right side part of the same image and swipe left it is going to the next image. How can i overcome this problem. Please help me.

Comment: Hi, your problem is quite different. Create separate question.

Comment: I have asked a question. please look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398288/image-zoom-issue-with-universal-image-loader-and-view-pager

Comment: what's the reason of Input/Output Error in UIL? @NOSTRA