# Android: code to zoom with ViewPager

Tags: android, image, android-viewpager, zooming

I'm trying to get a code to zoom in images implemented with `ViewPager` in Universal Image Loader. I've tried these but none is what I want:

- https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom --> Errors to import in Eclipse
- https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView --> It has this same error: [Image Zoom Issue with Universal Image Loader and View Pager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398288/image-zoom-issue-with-universal-image-loader-and-view-pager)
- https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView  --> It has this same error: [Image Zoom Issue with Universal Image Loader and View Pager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398288/image-zoom-issue-with-universal-image-loader-and-view-pager)

Someone knows a code to zoom in ViewPager? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ScrollingViewPager.java** https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/5475083

Once added to your project use that extended ViewPager in your layouts instead of the support library one. Then you can use https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView and just add `implements ScrollingViewPager.CanScrollCompat` to his TouchImageView to make it compatible and your done.

Comment: implementing all the above, I found difficulty when I zoom and drag on a image the view pager scrolls to next item

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to implement zoom in android is using the WebView.

Place web view in each page of your ViewPager.

And do something like this:

```
public static String zoomHTML = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
        "<html>\n" +
        "<head><title>Zoom Image</title></head>\n" +
        "<body>\n" +
        "<div>\n" +
        "    <img width=\"%d\" height=\"%d\" id=\"myCanvas\" src=\"data:image/png;base64,%s\"></img>\n" +
        "</div>\n" +
        "</body>\n" +
        "</html>";




String data = String.format(zoomHTML, screenHeight, screenWidth, base64StringImage);

zoomWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
zoomWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
zoomWebView.setInitialScale(100);
zoomWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", data, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```