# How to fit image in full screen in ImageViewTouch

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, zooming, universal-image-loader

I am using `[ImageViewTouch][1]` library to zoom a image instead of imageview.

```
<it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouch
           android:id="@+id/imageweb"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
           android:background="@drawable/bg_loading"
           android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

I want to load the image on ImageViewTouch control and the width of image will auto fits my screen.
How to fit only width and height both to my mobile screen?

Here when i do 3 times double tap means in 1st time its get zoomed in 2nd time also but in 3rd times its fits to height and width of the the device screen perfectly why its not fit at the time of first time.

But its not loaded fit to height and width at first time.? Please help me to sort out this issue.

I used this library classes May be i have to change here some thing.

```
1) [first][2]
2) [second][3]
```

Please Check Screenshots :

**When first time its loaded automatically :** 
[image]

After 3 times double tap means here first and second time zoom and 3rd time its fits perfectly why its not fitted at the time of first time when imageview loaded this image.

[image]

I already tried below answers but its not works.

Thank you for support

Answer (score 4):

In `it.sephirot.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouchBase` change the line

```
protected DisplayType mScaleType = DisplayType.FIT_IF_BIGGER;
```

in

```
protected DisplayType mScaleType = DisplayType.FIT_TO_SCREEN;
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. After trying a few workarounds without success, finally solved it switching to this library: https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [example app](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom/blob/master/ImageViewTouchTest/res/layout/main.xml):

```
<it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouch
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but as per this post i am not able to see image in my device if i am using same one from example application. see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359205/image-isnt-displayed-in-imageviewzoom

Answer (score 0):

```
<it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouch
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

I think fitXY is fit with the xy coordinate

Answer (score 0):

Try to call function setDisplayType(DisplayType.FIT_TO_SCREEN) for your imageView

Answer (score 0):

Scale type in the xml will not work.
You should use the library. Scale type is set in this class, change the scale type 
Here go to `it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouch`

in this class you can see `setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);` 
change this to `setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);`